# Compare 2 columns, then perform action on another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `TableX` in MySQL. There are 4 columns in `TableX`. The columns are `ColumnCompare_Now`, `ColumnCompare_Past`, `ColumnNumber_Now`, `ColumnNumber_Past`.

I want to write a MySQL statement that has the following logic;

```
    If ColumnCompare_Now == 'ActionNeeded' and ColumnCompare_Past == 'ActionNeeded', 
          then ColumnNumber_Now = `ColumnNumber_Now` + `ColumnNumber_Past`
```

MySQL knowledge is limited to simple Select Where statements. How can the above operation be implemented in MySQL? Meanwhile, I will try to figure this out myself while waiting for help from fellow members of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I know what you're trying to accomplish.  If you want to select a new column with this information, you can use a `case` statement:

```
select 
    case when ColumnCompare_Now = 'ActionNeeded' 
              and ColumnCompare_Past = 'ActionNeeded'
         then ColumnNumber_Now + ColumnNumber_Past
         else ColumnNumber_Now
    end as ColumnNumber_Now 
from tablex
```

---

And if you need this in an `update` query:

```
update tablex
set ColumnNumber_Now = ColumnNumber_Now + ColumnNumber_Past
where ColumnCompare_Now = 'ActionNeeded' 
    and ColumnCompare_Past = 'ActionNeeded'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I see case statement used in MySQL. An eye-opener

Answer (score 1):

```
     update TableX set ColumnCompare_Now=(select (ColumnNumber_NOw+ColumnNumber_Past) where ColumnCompare_Now=='ActionNeeded and ColumnCompare_Past=='ActionNeeded');
```

kindly try out this.