# Perform if-then-else-if action on column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is a follow-up to another question 
[Compare 2 columns, then perform action on another column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923750/compare-2-columns-then-perform-action-on-another-column-in-mysql/26923849#26923849)

I have a table named TableX in MySQL. There are 4 columns in TableX. The columns are ColumnCompare_Now, ColumnCompare_Past, ColumnNumber_Now, ColumnNumber_Past.

I want to write a MySQL UPDATE statement that has the following logic;

```
If ColumnCompare_Now == 'ActionNeeded' and ColumnCompare_Past == 'ActionNeeded', 
      then ColumnNumber_Now = `ColumnNumber_Now` + `ColumnNumber_Past`
else if ColumnCompare_Now == 'ActionNeeded' and ColumnCompare_Past != 'ActionNeeded'
      then ColumnNumber_Now = `ColumnNumber_Now` - `ColumnNumber_Past`
```

How can the else if statement be handled in MySQl?

Comment: Check out the `case` statement.

Comment: Is it a part of update or select ?

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty: It is part of an update statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For conditional update you can use `case`

```
update 
TableX
set
ColumnNumber_Now =
case 
when ColumnCompare_Now = 'ActionNeeded' and ColumnCompare_Past = 'ActionNeeded'
then `ColumnNumber_Now` + `ColumnNumber_Past`
when ColumnCompare_Now = 'ActionNeeded' and ColumnCompare_Past != 'ActionNeeded'
then `ColumnNumber_Now` - `ColumnNumber_Past`
end
```